# NodeJs ERROR - Parse error. primary expression expected

Tags: node.js, parsing

```
<%= if(queue * 30 + 10 < 60){ %>
<p><b>Time: </b><%= (queue * 30 + 10) %> minutes</p>
<% } else { %>
    <p><b>Time: </b><%= ((queue * 30 + 10)/60) %> hours</p><% } %>
```

Hello! How to fix it?

Comment: my guess is try to change the first `<%=` to `<%`  before your `if` statement since that is control flow and not output.

Comment: And it works. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what going on with all that syntax but heres something to compare with that is doing some JS logic.

```
const queue = 1;
const timeCheck = ((queue * 30) + 10);
const timeTrue = ((queue * 30) + 10);
const timeFalse = (((queue * 30) + 10)/60);


if( timeCheck < 60){
    `Time: ${timeTrue} minutes`
} else { 
  `Time: ${timeFalse} hours` 
}
```